# Matlab compiler runtime library

Tags: matlab, licensing, matlab-compiler

I have developed code on a m-file script in Matlab that communicates with a Measurement Computing USB-DAQ module, and I'm quite happy with that. The problem is that I don't want to purchase another license for the computer which is running the code. I have looked into [Matlab Compiler Runtime tools](http://www.mathworks.com/products/compiler/), and it claims that I can deploy my mcc built executables to be royalty-free. Does that mean I can install the MCRInstaller (copied from the computer in which the Matlab is installed) on the host computer running the final product?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. You install the Matlab Compiler Runtime (MCR) on the host computer that will be running the executable produced by the Matlab compiler.

Comment: Some years ago, the MRC was between 200 and 300 MB large.
The size of the actual application did not matter, the end user had to install the whole MRC.
How is that today?

Comment: As far as I know it is still that size. I evaluated it maybe 2 years ago.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can install MCR and using the Deployment Tool it's easy to create a software package with all the files you need inside.